# how to replace string having $ with null using sed command bash?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a varibale TMP have string and I am using that string to be replaced using sed command to null.

**TMP** variable  has string like this **"dec$|fgh$|yxz$"** and I am using this command

example.txt file contains string like this  **hello dec$|fgh$|yxz$**

```
sed -i "s/hello \"$TMP\"//g" /example.txt
```

But this command is not replacing?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas no I am not getting help from that answer

Comment: What have you tried? Also, your code seems to want to remove occurrences of `hello "dec$|fgh$|yxz$"` but you say your input has `hello dec$|fgh$|yxz$` instead. Get the text you want to remove into a `$lhs` variable (maybe `lhs="hello $TMP"`) and use the method given in the dup Q&A to get your `$escaped_lhs`.